# Reading value from String Array populated using ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I've got a `ListView` which populates a list of quotes from a String Array, however `onClick` I require the selected `<item>` to be read to a `String`. This is the code I use:

```
 ListView sample = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Samplelist);

    String[] backup = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, backup);

    sample.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public final void run()
                        {

                            String readItem;
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
        }


    sample.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

And here `sample.setAdapter(adapter)` seems to be an error and is underlined with red.

Is there a way to get this done correct? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: another error ? can you post logcat of error message

Comment: show `onClick ` method code

Comment: can you please post the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at layout of `simple_list_item_1` then you can find id of textview is `text1`.

You can define OnItemClickListener to your listview like this:

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

**EDIT:**

You can also try

```
String selectedItem = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

instead of

```
String selectedItem = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but actually what is `text1` and I am not using a TextView in my XML

Comment: text1 is id of your textview defined in simple_list_item_1 xml file provided by android sdk

Comment: It works, thanks, but again what exactly is `simple_list_item_1`

Comment: simple_list_item_1 is default list item layout provided by android sdk. you can also design your custom layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
            {

                String data=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to parse the text from `View` in `OnItemClickListener`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selectedItemText = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
        }
    });
```